# Как спарсить ссылку на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Всем добрый день. Пишу скрипт на Python, который парсит сайт магазина Лента  https://lenta.com/

В разных городах в ассортименте разные товары. Подскажите, **как получить ссылку определённого города, чтобы скрипт парсил именно эту ссылку, с этим городом?**

Comment: P.S. запускаю с впн, т.к. лента банит по ip сразу

Comment: А что в `response.content`? Вы пытались найти вручную теги которые Вы ищете супом?

Comment: print(soup.html) - html код всей страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел по ссылке и тот сайт, выбранный город и магазин, хранит в cookies, который будет передаваться в заголовке запроса **Cookie**.

Думаю, вам нужно заполнять в cookies следующие значения:

- lentaT2
- CityCookie
- Store

Вот так выглядит для Магнитогорска:

```
Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=<...>; CustomerId=<...>; ReviewedSkus=<...>; ASP.NET_SessionId=<...>; lentaT2=mgn; CityCookie=mgn; Store=0074
```

А вот так для Санкт-Петербурга:

```
Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=<...>; CustomerId=<...>; ReviewedSkus=<...>; ASP.NET_SessionId=<...>; lentaT2=spb; CityCookie=spb; Store=0718
```

---

В `requests` куки передаются параметром как словарь, [пример из документации](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies):

```
>>> url = 'https://httpbin.org/cookies'
>>> cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')

>>> r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
>>> r.text
'{"cookies": {"cookies_are": "working"}}'
```

---

**PS.**

Советую:

1. Заполнять HTTP заголовок `User-Agent`, так ваш скрипт будет сложнее отличить от обычного клиента, `requests` автоматически отправляет этот заголовок, но в нем указывает себя и свою версию
2. Использовать [requests.Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#id1), этот объект помнить куки, что ему сервер возвращал и сам их отправляет в запросах

Comment: Извините, а где вообще можно почитать про cookies? Я не силён в них, никогда с ними не работал

Comment: @Евгений, у мозиллы хорошие статьи по темам веба, например: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8 и, конечно, вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @gil9red извините за беспокойство, не могли бы вы глянуть вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135388/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-app-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8 не могу понять чем можно помочь.